Middleware need of a restart every morning
As the title says I have a annoying problem with my middleware.
Im using Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-182-generic x86_64).
But every morning I have to restart my service, then it runs perfectly during the day. I've been searching the systemctl journals and checking for different things that could cause it, read every post that could be similar to the problem but no go.
I have a fwupd that is causing some errors, but thats not connected to the service and shouldnt be a problem imo. So I thougth that I'd try my luck on this forum.
Oh, and I tried to do systemctl status service name and it says running, but the program connected to it wont work untill I restart it. Done free -h and no problem there either.
Edit: Its a .Net application but the service that im restarting is written in C#, also it started when I implemented OAuth2. I think that it has something to do with the cache? But I might just set up a cronjob to deal with it and be done.
Snus

I'd firstly check what you're actually running, as 20.04.1 implies you've not applied any security fixes since early 2021 (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/02/05/ubuntu-20-04-2-lts-released/ shows the ISO release date of 20.04.2, but installed system upgraded before that date)...   It could also be (based on kernel which is dated Fri, 07 Jun 2024 15:46:28 +0200) you're not running 20.04.1 but only 20.04 and read the .1 from a package detail misinterpreting its meaning.  If you are running 20.04.1 you need to apply security fixes ASAP.

Please edit the question and add some details. What is the exact name of the program you say acts up. It seems you have deliberately left that out. For example saying status and service name instead of the name of the actual service.

I mean as i mentioned, its the middleware between 2 program on a .NET application that is in need for a restart, might have left that out that its a .NET application but its a program that I've built myself and been working fine since 2020~ just started acting up earlier this year due to unknown reasons. It runs fine during the day but for some reason its acting up somewhere in the middle of the night meaning I have to get in to the office every morning to restart it in order for it to work. What more information is needed? As I said there is no error messages making it hard to debug.

Might also left out that it first started when I implemented OAuth2.

It's pretty difficult for anyone to troubleshoot an application you've written yourself.

I get that, but once again I'm just looking for pointers if anyone had similar problem with their application. Since its getting old restarting it every morning.
